# @profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer not working for me

Tags: firefox, webdriver, watir-webdriver

Folks,

I am having a problem using `@profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer`, so here is my code snippet:

```
@profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
@profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => @profile)
```

But when I run this I still get the security exception in firefox. Is there anything else that I need to set.

Thanks a lot

Comment: more of a webdriver thing, so added the webdriver tag.    an alternative is just add the certs from your test servers to the root cert store on test systems, that makes them treat those certs as trusted.  which pretty closely simulates what a user see's when they hit your production site which would have a valid trusted cert

Answer (score -1):

Do the following in your code snippet :

```
   @profile=Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
   @profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer=false
   @profile.secure_ssl = true 
   browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => @profile
```

You can also create a Custom firefox Profile. If you need a different profile